# If $Av \in V$ for any $v \in V$, prove that $A^{T}w \in V^{\perp}$ for any $ w \in V^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I am having problem trying to prove the following linear algebra question:

> Let A be a square matrix of order n and V be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Suppose $Av \in V$ for any $v \in V$, please prove that $A^{T}w \in V^{\perp}$
>   for any $ w \in V^{\perp}$

My thought process:

$V^{\perp}$ is defined as $span\{w \in V^{\perp} \  | \ w \cdot v = 0 \}$.

This implies that $ (Av) \cdot w = 0$.

However, I am not sure how to introduce the $V^{\perp}$ and $A^{T}$ into the equation. Could anyone please advise me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $Av \cdot w = v \cdot A^Tw$, for all vectors $v,w$.

(The former is the double sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i(A(v))_i = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j$$ while the latter equals

$$\sum_{i=}^n v_i ((A^T)(w))_i = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \sum_{j=1}^n (A^T)_{ij} w_j = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji} w_j$$ then interchange the order of $i$ and $j$. Abstractly the transpose of $A$ is *defined* by the first identity.)

Answer (score 1):

To prove $A^Tw \in V^\perp$ for every $w \in V^\perp$, you need to show that for any $v \in V$ and $w \in V^\perp$, $(A^Tw) \cdot v = 0$. To do so, try to rewrite expressions using the fact that $u_1 \cdot u_2 = u_1^Tu_2$ for any two vectors $u_1, u_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. For example, $(A^Tw) \cdot v = (A^Tw)^Tv$. Don't forget that you also know the value of $w \cdot (Av)$. (Why?)